# Reordering View Controller Scenes in Storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Is there anyway to change the order in which ViewController Scenes are displayed on the right-hand side in my Storyboard? I'm going to have several, and right now they are out of numerical order...it would be great if I could rearrange them to be in order. The way they're currently arranged is shown in the photo in the Dropbox link below:

[Storyboard screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1kvakxbdtrjzt1/Screen%20Shot%202014-08-08%20at%209.33.49%20PM.png)

Comment: Related question: [Change the listing order of the view controllers in Xcode storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585551)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the listing order of the view controllers in Xcode storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585551/change-the-listing-order-of-the-view-controllers-in-xcode-storyboard)

Comment: I tried implementing Denton's solution, but was unsuccessful (so far)

Comment: On Xcode 6.0.1 this solution works http://stackoverflow.com/a/16026765/1077481 (it's one of the answers in the same thread)

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the a item and giving it a couple of seconds before dragging it, worked for me.