# How to rearrange order of ViewControllers in Storyboard tree in Xcode 6?

Tags: xcode6

I suppose that it is very simple question, but I can not figure out how to manage order or `UIViewControllers` in the `Document Outline` (the list of `ViewControllers`)?

Comment: I agree that there is answer, @accfews, but I can not use it. I suppose that for Xcode 6 there is changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26815193/1163992

Comment: Sorry @accfews, I did not take attention on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order is defined by the order of the scenes in the XML (Right Click -> Open As.. -> Source Code) under the scenes node.

[image]

Note that on this XML, the "Splash" scene is first, followed by two navigation controllers and this is what is shown in the normal storyboard view.

```
<scenes>
        <!--Splash-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <!-- other data -->
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-876" y="-1364"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="ane-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <!-- other data -->
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-876" y="-1364"/>
        </scene>

        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="bne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <!-- other data -->
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-876" y="-1364"/>
        </scene>
</scenes>
```

[image]

Here however, I moved the scene node for splash below the navigation controllers and it updated the storyboard view accordingly.

```
<scenes>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="ane-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <!-- other data -->
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-876" y="-1364"/>
        </scene>

        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="bne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <!-- other data -->
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-876" y="-1364"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Splash-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <!-- other data -->
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-876" y="-1364"/>
        </scene>
</scenes>
```

[image]

Comment: 10x, @James Webster. I suppose that I can do it, but I was afraid not to damage Storyboard.

Comment: Do you use version control? (If not, why not?). Just commit before you make any changes and you can always revert. If you don't, just make a copy of your storyboard first and if it goes horribly wrong you always have a backup.

Comment: Yes, I use. I hope that there is a visual way. In general I agree with you - make a copy and then proceed.

Comment: It´s definitely very easy to do. Every single scene starts with <!-- SomeName and ends with </scene>. In Xcode 6 It´s worth doing it ;-)