# Why are my storyboard segues criss crossed?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

Just upgraded to Xcode 11, and I have a strange issue. My storyboard segues are all criss-crossed. They didn't used to be, and I can't figure out how to fix them.

[image]

I tried:

1. Recreating the segues. Didn't work.
2. Renaming them alphabetically. Didn't work.
3. Re-ordering the VCs from when they came. Didn't work.

Rearranging the VCs in the storyboard won't work because then the OTHER segues will be criss-crossed.

How do I fix this? It's really confusing to have the segues cross over each other.

Comment: I even completely re-created the VCs and remade the segues. They were no longer criss-crossed. Nice. But then when I restarted Xcode, they were crossed again. Aargh!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only been a few months, and I've just lived with the weird criss crossed segues. Then I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585551/change-the-listing-order-of-the-view-controllers-in-xcode-storyboard). Turns out, the segues use the storyboard order to determine segue order. Who knew? The order in which the controllers are listed in the Document Outline (panel to the left of the storyboard) dictate which segue shows up first.

I found the 'User.storyboard' file in the finder and opened it with TextEdit. I did a search for scenes, and simply rearranged the scenes to be in the correct order. No more criss-crossed storyboard segues. Nice!

Comment: Well, I spoke too soon. As soon as I restarted Xcode, the criss-crossed segues returned. Ugh.